# How can I get the Wowza Transcoder to work with Wowza 3.5.2 on Windows 2008?

Tags: windows, wowza, wowza-transcoder

I am using Wowza Media Server 3.5.2 to take IP Camera Streams, centralize them from one server and redistribute that to a web app.

I am trying to use the Wowza Add-On transcoder to transcode the streams to smaller bitrates so that they are accessible on Android phones. But I cannot get the Transcoder to work correctly.

The transcoder is registered with the system; in the log it shows the following:

```
Transcoder Streams Available: Unlimited
Transcoder Watermark: No
```

I am able to access the stream correctly at the following address: rtsp://IPADDRESS:1935/live/41.stream

But I cannot access the stream here: rtsp://IPADDRESS:1935/live/41.stream_720p

The system recognizes it as a stream, but it errors.  In the log it shows the following:

[image: error output screenshot]

I have used the default transcoder settings provided by the system and I have made sure that the Desktop Experience feature is installed on my server as [required](http://media.ttre.hu/Media/kolcseyarchiv/ejg/Wowza/wowza%20media%20server%203.5.2/readme.html).

Does anyone have any advice?  I have got to get this transcoder working so that I can get streaming working on Android. Thanks!